# Angular2 - Discreet Features in an Existing Application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In relation to my previous questions, this existing website application is a mix of ColdFusion pages and Adobe Flex/Flash movies.  We must replace the Adobe Flex/Flash movies with Angular, however, recreating the ColdFusion content in Angular is out of scope.

I'm not sure if this precludes having a master Angular application, as I am not sure how to implement the router for these non-Angular content pages.

I am thinking that I am going to have to create individual feature applications instead of modules of an application???

Any advice out there?

Comment: if my question is not clear enough, please ask for parts that you need clarification on so that I can improve the question, rather than just down voting without a comment, which is very unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after speaking with some experts, it seems that in this case, making discreet features as their own applications and handling the "routing" in the base coldfusion application, is the best option, unless I can get a scope change to include the base application.